# How to do scripting for silverlight application using loadrunner?

Tags: web-services, silverlight, encryption, loadrunner

I am completely new to Load Runner Performance testing tool.
I have an application where practitioner will do assessment for the patient.
The steps to do the assessment in that application is below:
1. Login to application.
2. Answer the security question.
3. Go to members page by clicking on Members tab.
4. Select the status for the assessment as Not started.
5. Select one member in the Not started assessment.
6. Begin the assessment.
7. Submit the assessment.
8. log out.

Between the steps 6 and 7 there are nearly 5 to 6 steps which are client side operations.
After I begin the assessment I will have different sections of assessment as below:
1. Clinical profile.
2. Subjective section.
3. Review of the system and physical examination.
4. General questions.
5. Current Diagnostics.
6. Preventive care.
7. Assessment and plan.

In each section I will have different controls like text boxes, check boxes buttons, etc..

After I complete filling one section I will have to click on next button to go to next section. This next button or any other action in the above mentioned section will not hit the server.

Silverlight protocol will start When I begin the assessment.
When I begin the assessment I will get the data(textboxes, checkboxes, buttons) of all above mentioned section in an XML file. This XML file will be encrypted.

After I submit the assessment, responses of filled section will be populated to XML file and the XML file will be sent as part of request in encrypted format.

When I recorded it in the loadrunner, I observed the response to the begin assessment request as totally encrypted format. Inorder to submit assessment I have to capture the data from Begin Assessment response and add the responses to the questions in each section to XML file and send that XML file as the response.

Please help me out on my question.

Comment: The application which I am working on is using XML webservices

Answer (score 0):

Loadrunner (LR) is more akin to API testing than UI (browser) testing. That is, all that LR is really concerned about is that final post. LR is oblivious to performance on the end user's browser and couldn't care less about Silverlight, Ajax, or any other browser side load. About the only impact Silverlight has on LR is to increase the recorded thinktime. LR wants to measure the impact of that final post on the networks, web server strings (including load balancers and application servers), and DB servers.  When you use VuGen to create the script all you should really see is that final POST and the generated XML in the body.  You can parameterize the XML values sent in the post using parameter lists (tables) to vary the responses across Vusers. That is up to you.